# Use a static background image for several fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, background

i have a problem. When i swipe from one fragment to another the background swipe with the text, instead of beeing static. How can the backround be static in all the fragments. What is my mistake?

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/hintergrund" />
```

one fragment of four (all have the same code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffdb00"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="141dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:text="Kollegah; King; Omega"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffdb00" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**New** `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/hintergrund" />

     <ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/hintergrund" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your viewpager in a FrameLayout with an ImageView.

```
<FrameLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/hintergrund" />

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

     </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</FrameLayout>
```

This way the ViewPager will show on top of your ImageView which will be static.

Comment: I updated my old post. Unfortunataly there is a error in line 2:
error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DominikKu Move xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" to the FrameLayout.

Comment: @DominikKu and remove the background attribute from your ViewPager